# ASP.NET localization translating HTML Content

Tags: asp.net

I am localizing an ASP.NET site using automatic feature , where it creates a local resource file and adds the meta keyword to asp.net controls. However I have a lot of HTML like below

```
<h2> Welcome to our page"</h2>
<li> Option one </li>
```

Is there a way to get these automatically translated using the automatic localize utility ?
I tried adding the runat="server" for  these tags but to no avail.

Also instead of localizing page by page is there  a way to localize bulk - it a directory or a site at one go

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [Localize control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize.aspx) for static text - for example,

```
<h2>
   <asp:Localize runat=server ID="WelcomeMessage" 
    Text="Welcome to our page" meta:resourcekey="WelcomeMessage" />
</h2>
```

Alternatively,

```
<h2>
   <asp:Localize runat=server ID="WelcomeMessage" 
    Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, WelcomeMessage %>" />
</h2>
```

You can also use syntax such as

```
<h2><%= Resources.WebResources.WelcomeMessage %></h2>
```

where `Resources.WebResources` is strongly typed resource class generated by Visual Studio resource generator. For across page resources, you can create global resources and then refer then using syntax as shown above (meta key will not work for global resources).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Vinay thanks for your input- Currently I am using Localize.However I have to manually translate pages. I was wondering if there is any automatic way of doing this

Comment: @josephj1989, if you were already using any control such as `literal` then localization feature from VS would have worked. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any tool that will help you in the current situation.