# How to give asp:Localize the localized text?

Tags: asp.net, localization, vwdexpress, visual-web-developer-2010

My ASP.NET page has some html:

**Default.aspx**:

```
<h2><asp:Localize meta:resourcekey="lblTitle" Text="Welcome to so" runat="server"></h2>
```

Now i want to localize that text. So i've created a resource file `Default.aspx.resx`. Following the examples of [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx), [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx), [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx), and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479795/asp-net-localization-translating-html-content) i create an `lblTitle.Text` entry:

[image]

Except that little red error indicator's hint says,

> The resource name "lblTitle.Text" is not a valid identifier.

How do i localize with `asp:Localize`? How do i localize with `meta:`? How do i create a resx?

---

**Update**: Renamed `App_GlobalResources` to `App_LocalResources`:

[image]

**Web.config** (partial):

```
<system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

---

**Update 2**: What i don't understand is that i'm following the instructions [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> To edit the resource file by using the Resource Editor
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, open Sample.aspx.resx.
>
>    In the **Resource Editor**, **under Value, are** the **Text** properties for each
>      of the controls that you placed onto your page. Changing the value
>      here will change the value for the default culture.
> 2. Set **ButtonResource1.Text** to **Edited English Text**.
> 3. Save the file.

i've also tried

- lblTitle.Text
- lblTitle-Text
- lblTitle_Text
- lblTitle
- lblTitleText

Comment: I updated my answer, should work as described now, I tested it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything right, but put your ressource file in the wrong folder. Use `App_LocalResources` instead of `App_GlobalResources`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) for more info on the difference between local and global ressource files:

> A local resources file is one that applies to only one ASP.NET page or user control (an ASP.NET file that has a file-name extension of .aspx, .ascx, or .master). You put local resource files in folders that have the reserved name App_LocalResources. Unlike the root App_GlobalResources folder, App_LocalResources folders can be in any folder in the application. You associate a set of resources files with a specific Web page by using the name of the resource file.

Comment: i can't be doing everything right, since it still complains about `lblTitle.Text`?

Comment: Did you move the Default.aspx.resx to App_LocalRessources? For me this makes the warning disappear. You are working with .NET 4.0, right?

Comment: Yes; i updated the question with the relevant snippet from web.config showing targeting `4.0`.

Comment: Try reopening the ressource file after you renamed the folder. The warning should vanish. Does it compile for you? Does the ressource text appear on the page?

Comment: You still have to append the '.Text', though, as you did in the beginning.

Comment: *"Try reopening the resource file after you renamed the folder"* That is a truly terrifying workaround, that definitely fixed the problem. Thank you!