# Localization not working for all the Markup / Tags in ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

While localizing the Content for an ASPX page through Visual studio and selecting the Option: "Generate Local Resources " the text is not getting localized for all HTMLs. FOr example, There are `<p>` tags and other server control tags like Label.

```
<p>Carrying out Localization on my First Website </p>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"></asp:label>
```

After selecting the Option: "Generate Local Resources " from "Tools" menu, below is what seen in markup:

```
<p>Carrying out Localization on my First Website </p>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" meta:resourcekey="labelResource1"></asp:label>
```

How can I localize the content placed inside `<p>` tags or any `<h1>`, `<h2>` tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479795/asp-net-localization-translating-html-content) provides an answer to your question on how to localize content placed inside html tags. You can store it in resource file and use it in html mark up as <%=Resources.WebResources.YourText%> as described there by VinayC where  Resources.WebResources is strongly typed resource class generated by Visual Studio resource generator.Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: What is Resources.WebResources   you mentioned ?

Comment: Edited my answer to describe what is Resources.WebResources. Again note that this update is just copy-paste from other stack overflow answer. Thanks to VinayC for the answer. Also, note that the discussion also has a link to MSDN documentation on resources, so please go through that as well in case if you are not already familiar with how to use resources and resource files, that should definitely help. In case if you are not able to see the link to discussion i am referring to in my answer, here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479795/asp-net-localization-translating-html-content

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use the <asp:localize /> control.

Answer (score 1):

The control that needs to be localized will have to run serverside.

You could place a `<asp:Label/>` or `<asp:Panel/>` inside the HTML `<p>`. A label will render to a `<span/>`, and a panel will render to a `<div/>`.

It is also possible to run the p at serverside : `<p runat="server" id="p1"></p>`.

Comment: Using Label or Panel control will render additional markup which i actually want to avoid.